# Why multishipping is disabled for items with decimal qty?

Tags: checkout, shipping, quantity

From Mage_Checkout_Helper_Data

```
/**
 * Check if multishipping checkout is available.
 * There should be a valid quote in checkout session. If not, only the config value will be returned.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isMultishippingCheckoutAvailable()
{
    $quote = $this->getQuote();
    $isMultiShipping = (bool)(int)Mage::getStoreConfig('shipping/option/checkout_multiple');
    if ((!$quote) || !$quote->hasItems()) {
        return $isMultiShipping;
    }
    $maximunQty = (int)Mage::getStoreConfig('shipping/option/checkout_multiple_maximum_qty');
    return $isMultiShipping
        && !$quote->hasItemsWithDecimalQty()
        && $quote->validateMinimumAmount(true)
        && (($quote->getItemsSummaryQty() - $quote->getItemVirtualQty()) > 0)
        && ($quote->getItemsSummaryQty() <= $maximunQty)
        && !$quote->hasNominalItems()
    ;
}
```

This check `!$quote->hasItemsWithDecimalQty()` will disable multishipping for items with decimal qty. Any one knows the reason behind it?

Answer (score 3):

My best guest is that the logic behind this is they need rounded quantities to split up the order.

Check the class `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Multishipping` method `getQuoteShippingAddressesItems`. The for loop for example takes steps of 1 to iterate through the quantity. Having a decimal quantity would probably cause issues. Stuff like values of less than 1 would cause the qty to be rounded to 0 in `_addShippingItem` and actually be skipped.

But this is just my guess, I might just be that it was done to keep the code less complicated

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to vote up this answer. I have the need to use decimal qty for multishipping, in my case, I need to split the order by items, there is no splitting the qty within an item. This means quite extensive modification of `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Multishipping`. From what I have seen, the code is complicated as it is, so this answer is probably on the dot.

Comment: @kiatng my thoughts exactly, I always try to as far away as possible from making any changes on this section :)

Comment: LOL. I spent 3 solid days on this and I can say it is a difficult hack, if anyone else needs to go down this path, be prepared for some unexpected problems.